# Simple foreach key value laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, foreach

this is my array :

```
array(5) {
  ["item 1"]=>
  int(1)
  ["item 2"]=>
  int(1)
  ["item 3"]=>
  int(2)
  ["item 14"]=>
  int(2)
  ["item 5"]=>
  int(3)
}
```

And this is my laravel view :

```
@foreach($cardActivite as $key => $value)
      <p>{{$key}} <b>{{$value}}</b></p>              
@endforeach
```

But my loop return '1', '2', ... as key and not 'item 1', ... and i want 'item ...')
But $value return the good element

Thanks

Comment: Yes it's because I use the function "array_count_values" before

Comment: @u_mulder can you help me ? 

Comment: Mistakes were made! Apologies! :3

Comment: If that's really the array that's in `$cardActivite`, I don't see how this is possible, which makes me thing it's not.

Comment: Can you show us your controller function?

Comment: If that truly is the result of your `$cardActivite` array, then it should display the key and values correctly... I'm going to wager it's not, so try dumping right above that loop and see what you get as a result of that array

Comment: Btw it's bad practice to use spaces in array keys

Comment: @JonStirling I love how similar our comments are, the phrasing are uncannily similar!

Comment: You said the key printed as `1,2,...` but **not** `0,1,2...` - let have long shot (probably not your issue though ) - do you get keys `1,2,3,14,5`? if you do look at @RomainB. comment

Comment: @JustCarty Oh thanks it was a careless mistake, I was doing the array_count_values ​​twice on the same list ‍♂️

Comment: @JustCarty Great minds, ey? ;)